# Ping a IP especifica

Tags: batch

Tengo el siguiente script, lo que deseo es enviar un ping sostenido a la IP señalada y me lo guarde en un .txt , pero solo me guarda la primer linea.

```
@echo off

:bucle


set a1=.
set a2=.
set /p IP=ESCRIBE IP;

ping -n 1 10.10.222."%IP%" | find "Respuesta" > a1.txt
ping -n 1 10.10.222."%IP%" | find "Tiempo de espera agotado" > a2.txt
set /p p1=< a1.txt
set /p p2=< a2.txt


echo %date% %time% %a1% %a2%
echo %date% %time% %a1% %a2% >> C:\Users\METAL\Desktop\log.txt

break >a1.txt
break >a2.txt

ping 127.0.0.1 -w 1000 -n 2 > NUL

GOTO bucle

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema reside en 2 cosas:

cuando usas la variable IP no la estás usando como tal  sino que esa variable según tu código representa el último número de una IP, me refiero a estas líneas:

```
ping -n 1 10.10.222."%IP%" | find "Respuesta" > a1.txt
ping -n 1 10.10.222."%IP%" | find "Tiempo de espera agotado" > a2.txt
```

Aquí tendrías dos opciones:

Cambiar el nombre de tu variable y lo que le pides al usuario con por ejemplo ultimoNumeroIp

```
ping -n 1 10.10.222."%ultimoNumeroIp%" | find "Respuesta" > a1.txt
ping -n 1 10.10.222."%ultimoNumeroIp%" | find "Tiempo de espera agotado" > a2.txt
```

O le quitas los numeros a estas dos lineas y usas de verdad la variable IP de tal manera que quedaría así:

```
ping -n 1 "%IP%" | find "Respuesta" > a1.txt
ping -n 1 "%IP%" | find "Tiempo de espera agotado" > a2.txt
```

y el otro problema que veo es el uso de las variables **%a1%** y **%a2%** cuando deberían de ser **%p1%** y **%p2%** según la definición que has hecho en las líneas:

```
set /p p1=< a1.txt
set /p p2=< a2.txt
```

Resumiendo el código de tu script quedaría así:

```
@echo off

:bucle
set a1=.
set a2=.
set /p IP=Escribe la IP a la que quieres hacer Ping:  

ping -n 1 %IP% | find "Respuesta" > a1.txt
ping -n 1 %IP% | find "Tiempo de espera agotado" > a2.txt

set /p p1=< a1.txt
set /p p2=< a2.txt

echo %date% %time% %p1% %p2%
echo %date% %time% %p1% %p2% >> log.txt

break > a1.txt
break > a2.txt

ping 127.0.0.1 -w 1000 -n 2 > NUL

GOTO bucle
```

NOTA: lo que pensabas que era la última línea no lo era sino que era el resultado de

```
echo %date% %time% %a1% %a2%
```

que como **%a1% %a2%** no tenían nada te escribía la fecha y la hora

un saludo y espero haberte ayudado

Answer (score 0):

error,de esa forma el bucle te pediria que escribas la ip en cada ciclo, mas abajo el script corregido, agregue al nombre del archivo por defecto la ip sobre la que estas escaneando para una mas facil identificacion de los logs que generes, saludos

```
@echo off

set /p IP=Escribe la IP a la que quieres hacer Ping:

:bucle
set b1=.
set b2=.

ping -n 1 %IP% | find "Respuesta" > b1.txt
ping -n 1 %IP% | find "Tiempo de Espera Agotado" > b2.txt
set /p p1=< b1.txt
set /p p2=< b2.txt

echo %date% %time% %p1% %p2%
echo %date% %time% %p1% %p2% >> log%IP%.txt

break >b1.txt
break >b2.txt

ping 127.0.0.1 -w 1000 -n 2 > NUL

GOTO bucle

pause
```